# Using GraphQL inside REST API for data querying

Tags: node.js, database, api, rest, graphql

I have an existing Node.js REST API that currently uses pg-promise for querying data from database. But instead I want to use GraphQL for querying the data from database. So, I want to use GraphQL only internally. All tutorials I found show how to build a GraphQL server. But can I use GraphQL only internally for querying data as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you'll still need to set up a graphql server.

Databases speak SQL and won't understand graphql directly. You need a separate application to receive the graphql and query the database.

```
+-------------+           +------------------+       +----------+
+ Application +-----------+ Application      +-------+ database +
+             +  graphql  + (graphql server) +  SQL  +          +
+-------------+           +------------------+       +----------+
```

Comment: Does it mean that my REST service makes requests to the graphql server, and the graphql server queries the database with SQL?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes it clearer to me! Do you have an advice for a tutorial which is like my scenario?

Comment: I cannot, because I don't know what your environment is, or what languages you are familiar with. I used graphql-jpa, which I would not recommend unless you already know Spring Boot.